# ModalTransitionStyle horizontal cover

Tags: ios

In my iPhone app I'm using several modal views. When I present a new viewcontroller I always use one of the transition animations

```
(UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical,UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve)
```

What I am looking for would be called `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverHorizontal`, but there's no such thing. However in a lot of applications (both ios and 3rd party) I see this horizontal covering transition.

Does anybody know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892451/how-to-do-a-horizontal-cover-segue-using-storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872076/is-there-a-way-to-perform-uimodaltransitionstylecoverhorizontal-not-fliphorizon) should answer your question. It's a bit of a hack, but basically by placing the view you're transitioning to out of the current view frame you can have more control over the animation.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I answer my question too.
What @Max Justicz said is one way to do it. 
The other way is to have it done in a UINavigationController.

You create the UIViewController where you want to navigate from:

```
UIViewController* controller1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
```

Also create a UINavigationController and init it with the controller

```
UINavigationController* controllerNVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: controller1];
```

Then in "controller's .m" file when you want to navigate, do it like this.

```
UIViewController* controller2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller2 animated:YES];
```

this will push a controller2 onto controller1.

When you want to go back from controller2 just call this:

```
[[self navigationController]popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This way you can have a horizontalcover animated way to navigate between views